# active pull requests already exists, force pushed into main branch

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have 3 active pull requests, force pushed all changes into main branch. What of those active pull requests. What are my options, can I simply just delete them? Will I run into any conflicts.

Comment: "force pushed all changes into main branch" What? Why did you do _that?_ Surely that negates the whole point of pull requests. Indeed, I'm surprised that your remote is configured in a way that allows pushing direct into the main branch in the first place.

Comment: You literally can't delete a GitHub pull request. You can *close* it, but it remains there, in the GItHub database associated with your GitHub repository.

Answer (score 0):

If all the necessary changes are already integrated into 'main' branch, and assuming these active PRs had 'main' branch as their destination as well, you could just delete them as they don't contain any unmerged changes.